# Excel: move the contents of the row to a specific column based on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, rows

I have a large excel file with consistent columns but they're not placed too accurately;
The example in the photo is illustrative to my problem; I'm only interested in the information after the "country" column.
Therefore, within each row, I would like to
1. check each row to find a specific string of characters - in this case "Spain".
2. move the row so that the cells with the strings found are all on the same column.

In the example below, all the rows should be moved so that "Spain" is under column F - arranging the rest of the info with it.

[image: moving rows to specific column ID]

Answer (score 0):

If word Spain isn't changed, use this VBA code:

```
Sub MoveCoun()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rFind As Range
Dim r As String
Dim m As Integer
LastRow = 1000
For n = 1 To LastRow
    r = n & ":" & n
    Range(r).Select
    With Range(r)
        Set rFind = .Find(What:="Spain", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            If rFind.Column < 6 Then
                m = 6 - rFind.Column
                Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, m)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            ElseIf rFind.Column > 6 Then
                m = rFind.Column - 6
                Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, m)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        End If
        End With
Next
End Sub
```